# Making an array with Strings and range of Integer merged

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to make a function that generates an array consists of Strings, and integers in range combined as a whole String. For example:

```
let fruit = "apple"
let numbers = Array(1...10)
let format = ".jpg"

->

["apple1.jpg", "apple2.jpg", "apple3.jpg", ..... "apple10.jpg"]
```

How can I combine a defined String with range of integers and put them in an array? Apologize for a newbie question. Much appreciated. <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is you can directly use `map` on your `range`.

```
let array = (1...10).map({ "apple\($0).jpg" })
print(array) //["apple1.jpg", "apple2.jpg", "apple3.jpg", ..... "apple10.jpg"]
```

Comment: Amazingly simple. Thanks Nirav D. But what if I need to use different names of fruit? I first wanted to define fruit as a separate variable, and then make something like this to make an array. Still learning.

Comment: @Gavin Simply change `"apple\($0).jpg"` with `"\(fruit)\($0).jpg"` now it will use value of `fruit` instead of static string `apple`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
func mergeStringAndInt(_ prefix: String, intArray: [Int], postfix: String) -> [String] {
    return intArray.map {String(format: "%@%d%@", prefix, $0, postfix )}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the like -

```
func resultArray() -> NSMutableArray {
var your_Array = NSMutableArray()
for item in numbers {
    let combinedStr = "\(fruit)\(item).\(format)"
    your_Array.add(combinedStr)
   }
    return your_Array
}
```